# Excel VBA search a column and place a value on the next cell

Tags: vba

I have created an exam using Excel 2013.
Sheet1 >> "Summative Test Lesson 1" >> this is where the exam is located.
Sheet2 >> "Grade 7A_Students" >> the list of student is created.
Declared score as integer, it store the score
declared nameStud as string that store the name of the students.

My problem is,
I need to look at column B of sheet2, if a cell in column B contains the name stored in nameStud, the score must be displayed in the adjacent cell.

Here's the interface of the my sheet 1. The student will put her/his student number in b1. Using lookup, b2 will display the name of that student taken from sheet 2. Now the student will answer. when she he click the submit button, the worksheet will be protected so the studentwon't be able to edit.

L5 will display the score by counting the correct answer.

What I need to do now is to transfer that score to sheet2 on the cell adjacent to the name of the student who took the exam.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question... Still, check out the spreadsheet function VLOOKUP. I believe this will solve your problem without the need of any VBA.

Comment: Here's the interface of the my sheet 1. The student will put her/his student number in b1. Using lookup, b2 will display the name of that student taken from sheet 2.

Now the student will answer from a to k. when she he click the submit button, the worksheet will be protected so the studentwon't be able to edit. L5 will display the score by counting the correct answer.

What I need to do now is to transfer that score to sheet2 on the cell adjacent to the name of the student who took the exam..

Comment: Exactly. You need to set into B2 a formula like this: `=IF(B1="","",VLOOKUP(B1,<range to look for value>,<column offset>,FALSE))`. If your data is in columns instead of rows, there is an equivalent function HLOOKUP. Simply Google on these functions.

Comment: (After your update to your comment) Understood. Still, all you are describing can be done without VBA.

Comment: but, if another student will be taking the exam, of course the value of the score will be different. how can i retain the score next to the name? in sheet 2

Comment: I see... Now you have another problem. How will you prevent from two users updating the file at the same time?

Comment: I have 45 students listed in sheet2. all of them will take the exam one by one. after one student answer the exam, when he or she click submit, the score will appear in L5 sheet1. That score which is L5 must be put in sheet2 next to the name of the student. then I will click the reset button that will remove the protection of the sheet and reset the answer so that the next student will take the test.. until all 45 had taken the test

Comment: I see... So you WILL need a small vba for the submit and reset buttons. Now I got it. By the way, I'm not sure you need to remove protection of a hidden sheet to update it using VBA.